ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing website from mobile data
I have an API service built on Python-Flask & hosted on a AWS EC2 subdomain e.g. api.example.com, I have installed lets-encrypt-certbot certificate with CN (wildcard) as *.example.com
My react app is hosted on different server and domain as example.com, but when I am trying to access https://wwww.example.com, it calls API which is giving an error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
It works well when I connected to wifi but getting an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error when I access it from mobile.
Looking for some help here
my nginx conf file is as
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        
        server_name api.example.com;

    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305';

        # HSTS (optional)
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;               
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
            #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';

    
        }
    }


I don't think this question contains enough information to be answerable. We'd probably need some kind of dump of the SSL handshake/negotiation in order to figure out why the error occurs. But if WiFi vs cellular data is the only difference, then that would indicate some misconfiguration outside of your control. Could range from stale cached DNS entries to your network provider trying to MitM you.

@Siguza.. thanks for the response .. I am getting below error in nginx error file
2024/07/07 03:10:43 [crit] 20202#20202: *142 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.41.200.104, server: 0.0.0.0:443
working fine for IPv4 but unable to connect IPv6 server when I did ssl server check.
I have all the DNS entries for domain and subdomin for IPv4 and IPv6.
The APIs are hosted on AWS.. anything i misssing there ?

The issue was with AWS.. IPV6 wasnt assigned to the EC2 instance.. after assignment everything is working fine.
